# Jquery ajax Success function is not working in Node.js application

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using node.js Angular.js and mongodb for my sign up application.I am making ajax call for sending user's sign up information to DB through server but what i found ,its success function is not working at all although all the data is inserting into DB but after sometimes the error function is executing.I want do something inside this success function.Please check my code below.

> loginController.js:

```
function loginController($scope){
    $scope.hidespan=true;
    var userInfo=[] ;
    $scope.signup=function(){
        if (document.getElementById('email').value==''){
            $scope.hidespan=false;
            $scope.emailerror="* This field can not be blank";
            $('#email').addClass("err-email");
        }else{
            var value=validateEmail($('#email').val());
            if (value==false){
                $scope.hidespan=false;
                $scope.emailerror="Email format is not correct"
            }else{
                userInfo.push({email:$scope.email});
            }
        }
        if($('#fname').val()==''){
            $scope.hidespan=false;
            $scope.fnameerror="* First name field canot be blank";
            $('#fname').addClass("err-email");
        }else{
            var fvalue=validateFname($scope.fname);
            if(fvalue==true){
                $scope.hidespan=false;
                $scope.fnameerror="User first name should contain more than 3 letter";
                $('#fname').addClass("err-email");
            }else{
                userInfo.push({fname:$scope.fname});
            }
        }
        if ($('#lname').val()==''){
            $scope.hidespan=false;
            $scope.lnameerror="* Last name field canot be blank";
            $('#lname').addClass("err-email");
        }else{
            userInfo.push({lname:$scope.lname});
        }
        if($('#pass').val()==''){
            $scope.hidespan=false;
            $scope.passerror="* Password field canot be blank";
            $('#pass').addClass("err-email");
        }else{
            var pass=validatePass($scope.password);
            if(pass==false){
                $scope.hidespan=false;
                $scope.passerror="password length should not less than 6";
                $('#pass').addClass("err-email");
            }else{
                userInfo.push({password:$scope.password});
            }
        }
        if($('#codeest').val()==''){
            $scope.hidespan=false;
            $scope.codeerror="* code field canot be blank";
            $('#codeest').addClass("err-email");
        }else{
            userInfo.push({code:$scope.code});
            console.log('user',userInfo);
        }
        if(userInfo.length==5){
            console.log('user',userInfo);
            var sentData={email:userInfo[0].email,fname:userInfo[1].fname,lname:userInfo[2].lname,password:userInfo[3].password,code:userInfo[4].code}
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:sentData,
                url:"/signUp",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('data',data);
                    $('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show();
                },
                error:function(err){
                    console.log('error',err);
                    $('#signupalert').css('display','block');
                    $scope.error=err;
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is my server side code for DB operation.

> admin.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongojs');
db = 'swarga',
collections = ['user'],
db = mongo.connect("127.0.0.1:27017/"+db, collections);
exports.signup=function(req,res){
    console.log('req',req.body);
    db.user.insert({email:req.body.email,fname:req.body.fname,lname:req.body.lname,password:req.body.password,code:req.body.code},function(err,docs){
        console.log('docs',docs)
    })
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `res.send(<some response>);` in your server. You must send some response back to the client.

Comment: @ yarons :Yes i did this.After some time i found that i am missing to send respose back.